# Load list of floats from file to MLMultiArray

Tags: ios, swift, macos, coreml

I have a file that contains floats, generated by python

```
arr = ... # some np.ndarray of shape (H, W, C)
arr.tofile('floats.b')
```

I want to convert that to an `MLMultiArray`.

What I was thinking is to use the following initializer:

```
init(dataPointer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer, 
     shape: [NSNumber], 
     dataType: MLMultiArrayDataType, 
     strides: [NSNumber])
```

But I can't figure out how to get an UnsafeMutableRawPointer.

I was trying to:

- Get it from a `Data` object. But it seems that only wants to yield UInt8?
- Get it via `fopen`. Also UInt8?

```
var data = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: 32 * 32 * 220)
fgets(data, Int32(32 * 32 * 220), file)  # Compile Error, needs UInt8.
```

How is this done? What I need to do is read 4 bytes at a time into a `[Float]`.

---

I was able to write the following but I'm not sure I get this right.

```swift
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
var arr = data.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<Float>) -> Array<Float> in
    return Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(
        start: bytes,
        count: data.count / MemoryLayout<Float>.size))
}

arr.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { ( pointer: inout UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Float>) in
    let raw = UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer(pointer)
    let arr = try! MLMultiArray(dataPointer: raw.baseAddress!,
                                shape: [1, 32, 32, 220],
                                dataType: MLMultiArrayDataType.float32,
                                strides: [901120, 28160, 880, 4])
}
```

Specially the memory management seems unclear.

Comment: Your `floats.b` just consist of 4 byte floats, packed end on end, right? No newlines, commas, etc.? If so, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62442974/3141234 You can read the entire file's content into a `Data`, and then reinterpret that `Data` into a `[Float]`.